# STtimulated Emission Depletion (STED) microscopy theory

Tags: microscopy, imaging

I am recently reading [STED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STED_microscopy) microscopy. In the Wiki, STED is described to be a process that the atoms of the flurophore in the periphery of the focal point is stimulated to emit light of wavelength that is longer than the normal light, which makes it easy to be seperated. But the [original paper](https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-24-14-954) just said that the light is **depleted** by the STED light. I don't know how the **deplete** actually works.

Comment: It seems that there is actually an Emission Filter before the detector that filter out the undesired light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term **depleted** means that less excited fluorophores are allowed off-axis than in absence of the STED beam (ie than in confocal microscopy).

In STED you have a sort of "Point Spread Function (PSF) engineering". The doughnut beam (with a zero in the center) surrounds the typical excitation beam. The excitation beam does what a normal confocal laser does: it excites the fluorophores in a diffraction limited volume. The intense focused doughnut beam is red-shifted from the excitation beam, and its photons force the excited fluorophores in the periphery of the excited volume to emit by stimulated emission light. this emission is at the wavelength of the doughnut beam, which indeed can be filtered out by filters.

So the excited confocal volume of fluorophores is kept **depleted** of excited fluorophores by the STED beam. So only the fluorescence of the ones at the center of the doughnut is detected, effectively reducing the size of the excited PSF.

Comment: Thanks! so the key idea is that the stimulated light is rea shifted, right? Can you share some links to papers on that phenomenon?

Comment: yes, the STED beam and the stimulated light are red shifted wrt the central fluorescence excitation. Check [here](http://zeiss-campus.magnet.fsu.edu/referencelibrary/superresolution/sted.html) for references